# Performing hierarchical clustering on a large data set

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, matlab

I have been applying complete linkage on about 5,000 points using matlab with no problem. I want to extend this method to much more elements. It would take me a long time to process my data to test it, so I would like to know whether someone has already applied this algorithm on matlab with so much data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not at all large data.

A decent implementation of single-link clustering should take less than 10 minutes for 100k instances on a single core.

Nevertheless, you may want to look at algorithms that scale better than $O(n^2)$ (or $O(n^3)$, depending on your linkage criterion!) and memory. Best is, you use some algorithm with indexing support, so it can run in $O(n \log n)$, if you ever need really larger data. There are plenty of choices - probably not in Matlab, though.